# After adding a new row why aren't my bound controls updating? 

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, dataset, binding, collectionviewsource

I'm using wpf drag and drop databinding to datasets. I generate a new datatable row using the AddNew method of the BindingListCollectionView. I set values on the new row and call CommitNew on the BindingListCollectionView. **I expect to see my assigned values in the bound controls but they are all blank.** If I save the changes to the database the controls are then updated, but I want the user to see my assigned values before calling UpdateAll on the TableAdapterManager.

Background:
I've created a strongly typed dataset in a project separate from my wpf application. My wpf app references the dataset application. I added an object datasource in the wpf app pointing to the typed dataset. I dragged fields/controls from the datasources window to the wpf designer window. The generated xaml includes a Window.Resources section with a CollectionViewSource accurately bound to my dataset and datatable. This CollectionViewSource is the DataContext for the controls that I dragged to the design surface. All of the controls use TwoWay databinding.

When the window loads I grab a reference to the xaml's CollectionViewSource (using FindResource). I then grab a reference to the view property of the CollectionViewSource and cast it to a BindingListCollectionView. Now I use the AddNew method of the BindingListCollectionView to generate a new row (which AddNew returns as an object).  I cast the object to a DataRowView and access it's Row property. I then cast the row to a strongly typed datatable row (generated by the DataSet designer). Now I assign values to some of the datatable row columns. I call CommitNew on the BindingListCollectionView. Finally I call MoveCurrentToFirst on the CollectionViewSource.

Problem:
Using a watch expression I can see the data is in the SourceCollection of both the CollectionView and the BindingListCollectionView. **Can anyone explain why the bound controls do not show the data unless I save the changes to the database?**

Code (generated XAML not shown):

```
Private WithEvents _cvsScanData As System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource
Private WithEvents _blcvScanData As System.Windows.Data.BindingListCollectionView

_cvsScanData = CType(Me.FindResource("Dt_tblScanDataViewSource"), System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewSource)

_blcvScanData = CType(_cvsScanData.View, BindingListCollectionView)

Dim newRow As LabDataSet.dt_tblScanDataRow = CType(CType(_blcvScanData.AddNew, System.Data.DataRowView).Row, LabDataSet.dt_tblScanDataRow)

newRow.SampleID = "testSampleID"
newRow.MachineID = "testMachineID"

_blcvScanData.CommitNew()   

_cvsScanData.View.MoveCurrentToFirst()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple fix is to **call the Refresh method of the BindingListCollectionView** after calling CommitNew.

```
_blcvScanData.Refresh()
```

I stumbled across this answer to my own question via intellisense. If anyone can explain why refresh is necessary I'd appreciate it. I expected the INotifyPropertyChange interface to update the bound controls obviating the need to call refresh.